# WebDriver FirefoxDriver, executar click em checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver

Estou criando um robô para logar em uma pagina, marcar um checkbox e efetuar um download de um arquivo de exportação. Porem não estou conseguindo executar o checked em um checkbox. Estou usando Selenium WebDriver com FirefoxDriver com o método via XPath:

```
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.Url = "";

                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath
    ("//div[@class='d-flex flex-row']//input[@type='checkbox']")).Click();
```

Imagens do site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dá algum erro ou só não clica?

Comment: @LucasMiranda só não clica!

Comment: Já tentou clicar no `span` ou  no `svg`? Isso ja aconteceu comigo, quando não consigo clicar diretamente no `input` de um `checkbox` tento clicar no elemento que esta a cima dele

Comment: @Tmilitino não estou muito familiarizado com montar o xPath corretamente! Usando o exemplo de cima vc poderia me mostrar como ficaria o xPath para clicar no span ou svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como falei no comentário,  o seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim, só mudaria o elemento que iria procurar. Como o input esta "encoberto" por outros elementos fica mais difícil realizar algum tipo de ação com ele.

```
 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.Url = "";

                driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='jss78']")).Click();
```

Obs: olhando melhor o `HTML` não dá para clicar no `svg` porque ele está marcado como oculto `hidden=True`.

Você pode aprender mais sobre XPATH neste [link](http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XPath_tutorial_-_basics)